# Determine if $f_x$ and $f_y$ are continuous at $(0, 0)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$$
f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
      \dfrac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/3}} &\text{if } (x,y)\ne (0,0) \\
      0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases} 
$$
Are $f_x$ and $f_y$ are continuous at $(0, 0)$?

I calulated the partiale derivative 
$$
f_x = \frac{4x^3+8xy^2}{3\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}}
$$ But then...?

Comment: Use polar coordinates and see if ur function $f_x$ converges to the same limit independent of the angle $\theta$. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Tamim but there's a h involved now; I think as Tres mentions, it is better to use the definition of derivatives; but the problem for is that it is very hard to compute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the definition of partial derivatives.

\begin{align*}
{f_x}\left( {x,y} \right) =\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{{f\left( {x + h,y} \right) - f\left( {x,y} \right)}}{h}\hspace{0.5in}{f_y}\left( {x,y} \right) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{{f\left( {x,y + h} \right) - f\left( {x,y} \right)}}{h}
\end{align*}

Remember that a continuous function is a function with $f(a)=\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$

Let's calculate $f_x(0,0)$, 
\begin{align*} 
{f_x}\left( {0,0} \right) & =\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{{f\left( {0 + h,0} \right) - f\left( {0,0} \right)}}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{{f\left( {h,0} \right) - 0}}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{1}{h}\dfrac{h^2}{(h^2)^{1/3}}=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{h}{h^{2/3}} \\ &= 0.
\end{align*}
Then you do the same to $f_y(0,0)$ and compare whith the property $f(a)=\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$

Comment: I tried to do it with the definition of partial derivatives, but the h in the denomination don't cancel out and ends up with a messy function

Comment: I edit the answer check it.

Comment: but are we allow to plug in 0? I thought we need to keep it in variable and the end result will be a function of say, x.

Comment: Yes we are allow to plug this. If you do this you are using the definition and It is correct.

Comment: so I figure out both of the limit goes to 0, and because they have the same limit, they are continuous?